# Queuing functions so they fire synchronously

Tags: c#, synchronization, queueing

I have an application which controls some stepper motors using a propriety DLL. I am finding I occasionally get errors where it seems as though the functions I am using to communicate with the controllers are firing too close together and not allowing time for the controller to respond.

```
private void CommandZ(string command)
{
    DMX_UMD_API.Flush(hUSBDevice_Z);

    string tmpString = "";
    bool status;
    status = DMX_UMD_API.performaxSendAndGetReply_Z(hUSBDevice_Z, command, out tmpString);
}

public string loopCommands_Z(string command)
{
    DMX_UMD_API.Flush(hUSBDevice_Z);
    string tmpString = "";
    bool status;
    status = DMX_UMD_API.performaxSendAndGetReply_Z(hUSBDevice_Z, command, out tmpString);
    if (status)
    {
        return tmpString;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

How can I queue the functions so they occur synchronously?

Comment: I assume the library call internally async and return to you right away even if it hasn't finished. There must be a state accessible into the library telling you that it finished processing or something similar. Otherwise you would have to implement your own buffer using a list of command and a thread running each X amount of milliseconds / seconds to execute the next command requested but that's a more difficult terrain.

Comment: They already seem to execute synchronously. Do you call them from different threads? In that case you have a shared resource, which must be protected against concurrent access. You'd probably do that with a `lock` or similar measures as with any other shared resource.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're probably looking for something like this: `bool isRunning = false; private void CommandZ(string command) { if (isRunning) return; isRunning = true; //DoStuff; isRunning = false }`

Comment: @Franck and it would be quite fragile to base it on timing in a non-realtime system. Would be more like "guessing". Maybe it's just me, but I don't like guessing when it comes to hardware with moving parts. I don't know the application, but anything could happen from damaged HW to people getting injured ...

Comment: If I understand properly, a simple delay at the end of every function should help.  It is generally stupid, but in this case `Thread.Sleep() ` might be actually useful.  Of course, the more elegant approach is to use `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Unrelated: Why are these two separate functions? To me that's duplicate code. You could always use `loopCommands` and just ignore the returned string, where you now use `CommandZ`. And the name is also confusing. There is no "loop".

Comment: @Nick: How long should the delay be? Should it be dependend on the number of steps? How large is the corridor of runtime per step of different motors? ... I really, really do think simply adding a delay is a bad idea.

Comment: @MJ2507 Can you please link to some documentation of the API? It's hard to suggest something useful without knowing anything about the system. If Franck's suspicion is correct and you can poll some status while the motor is moving, I could suggest a pattern I used in a similar application.